# apply/ map function to prior row

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

still new to functions and its application I would like to create a new column `D` for a dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 5], [4, 6, 7]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

    A   B   C
 0  1   2   3
 1  1   3   5
 2  4   6   7
```

the column `D` and its content shall be created by the help of a function, I though about this fashion:

```
 def my_func(B, C):
     if C > B.shift(1):
         df['D'] = 'right'
     return df['D']
 else:
      df['D'] = 'left'
      return df['D']
```

So in plain words: if the value in `C`  is higher than the value of `B` from the previous row than the cell gets 'right', else 'left'.
I do not get it to run, somehow the shift is not accepted or I get the error message

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any help welcome on how best use functions for such a task and also apply shift().

EDIT: I am looking for a "function version" of the solution because this shall be a procedure that shall frequently be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['D'] = np.where(df.C > df.B.shift(), 'left', 'right')
print (df)
   A  B  C      D
0  1  2  3  right
1  1  3  5   left
2  4  6  7   left
```

If need function:

```
def f(B, C):
    df['D'] = np.where(C > B.shift(), 'left', 'right')
    return df

print(f(df.B, df.C))
   A  B  C      D
0  1  2  3  right
1  1  3  5   left
2  4  6  7   left
```

Or:

```
def f(B, C):
    df['D'] = np.where(C > B.shift(), 'left', 'right')
    return df.D

print(f(df.B, df.C))
0    right
1     left
2     left
Name: D, dtype: object
```

Comment: I like this solution @jezrael, but how can I implement this in a function?

Answer (score 3):

Lets suppose this is a pandas dataframe named `df`

```
A   B
0   0   
1   1   
2   2   
3   3   
4   4
```

Now lets suppose I apply shift to `B` column

What'll happen is

```
A   B
0   NaN   
1   0 
2   1   
3   2   
4   3
```

So now when you'll try to compare it'll pop you an error, as it is trying to compare a number with something which is Not a Number(NaN)

So now it depends what you want to do with the first row....

Now talking about why this particular snippet won't work. 
What you are trying to do is to send a series as a parameter and comparing them to update a single row....
`C > B.shift(1)` note that C and B are series, and this is the reason why that error popped. So to avoid this you'll have to check the condition for each row and update `D`

Which can be done by

```
df['D'] = ['right' if i > j else 'left' for i, j in zip(df.B.shift(), df.C)]
```

Easy right!? Happy Coding!

Comment: your explanation why I did not get far clears things up a  lot, @hashcode55. thanks for this. I just need to get a better grasp of the implementation of the zip function. I would have never found that myself....

Answer (score 2):

You could also just:

```
df.loc[df.C > df.B.shift(), 'D'] = 'left'
df.D = df.D.fillna('right')

   A  B  C      D
0  1  2  3  right
1  1  3  5   left
2  4  6  7   left
```